# Multiplication on the result of sql's row using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I want to time a decimal result in sql, like this :

```
// script 
$currency =mysqli_fetch_array( $db->query("SELECT value FROM `currency` where `currency_code` = 'USD' ") );
// $currency['value'] = 0.00001234;
// type : float(15,8)
$result = 5000 * $currency['value'] ;
// end script
```

and the result is 0.

I want a real result.. What must I change ?

Comment: float with currency?  I suggest you re-examine your choice of data type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: I very much doubt that the values and value types are what you say they are. You should start with a `var_dump($currency);`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to type cast your result value into float first and then make the multiplication.

```
 $currency =mysqli_fetch_array( $db->query("SELECT value FROM `currency` where `currency_code` = 'USD' ") );

 // $currency['value'] = 0.00001234;
 // type : float(15,8)
 $result = 5000 * (float)$currency['value'];
 // end script
```

Give it a try and let me know the result please.

Comment: can you give me that code? 
I dont know what must I change. 
please.

Comment: Just add (float)  infront of $currency['value'];
I already gave it in the answer.

         $result = 5000 * (float)$currency['value'];

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in query like this:

```
$currency =mysqli_fetch_array( $db->query("SELECT (value * 5000) as totalVal FROM `currency` where `currency_code` = 'USD' ") );
```

And you can use "totalVal" directly to access the value.